# Applying different filters on different rows of a spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe which has 5 columns  ColA,ColB,country,start_time,end_time. I need to form a new df from the existing df after doing the below processing

```
  If df.country == US then we have to do df.filter(start_time < todays date)

  For remaining countries we have to do df.filter(end_time < todays date)
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow. This looks like some homework task to me, so please have look at [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822). The pseudo code is given, so what have you tried and where are you stuck? The question as it is does not show any effort nor any research. If you do not edit this question it will probably be closed soon.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by applying two filters, first on country then on date like

```
df.filter(((f.col('country')=='US') & (f.col('start_time')<datetime.datetime.now())) |
          ((f.col('country')!='US') & (f.col('end_time')<datetime.datetime.now())))
```

Comment: But you want to filter data....case can be used when you want to create new column based on these columns value